# Sencha touch and google Oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, sencha-touch

I am developing [Sencha Touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) application and I have been using Oauth 2.0 for authorization.  The first time it is run, the application asks for `user_code`, is authorized, and works fine.  However, when I close and then reopen the application, it again asks for authorization (the request is sent again) and asks for `user_code`.

I read "Using OAuth 2.0 for Devices" but it did not help.

Comment: Standard English grammar, spelling and punctuation.

Comment: @WayneConrad I am developing a senhca touch application. In this we used Oauth for authorization.  we packaged using cordova and created .apk file. When th user opens the app its asks for his credentials and authenticates and provides a token. The problem is when the user closes and opens app it asks for credentials again and a fresh token is getting generated. It should not be so..once authorized it should not ask again...